# Get all the Table names in particular database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and want to get all the tables name in a particular database `STUDENT` through a SQL query.

How is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You want to query sys.objects and look for everything with the type description 'USER_TABLE'. You could use a query like this;

```
SELECT 
*
FROM STUDENT.sys.objects
WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

The FROM clause has the usual format: DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName.

Or as marc_s mentions, you can use sys.tables instead;

```
SELECT 
*
FROM STUDENT.sys.tables
```

Comment: Or you could just use the **more focused** `sys.tables` catalog view and not have to deal with the `type_desc` anymore....

Comment: @Rich benner my database name is STUDENT and i want to get the names of all tables only exist into the STUDENT database, so how can i use above query according to my database

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You want the names of all of the tables within another table?

Comment: @Rich Benner Sorry my mistake actually STUDENT is my database name

Comment: Yes, so your database 'STUDENT' contains a number of tables. The query above will list all tables that exist within your database. I don't understand the complication here.

Comment: yes its working fine thank@Rich Benner for your suggestions

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your problem.

Comment: SO Sorry @Rich Benner I am new member and reputation less than 15 that's why I could not vote your answer. vote my question so that I would eligible for voting

Comment: @RichBenner Thanks a lot, now I am eligibled to accept any question

Comment: No worries :) there's a tick under the voting arrows on the answer. If you tick this then it shows others that the question has been answered (and gives reputation to the answerer)